# How to call the value when it is a list within a dictionary to use with the Discord API

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am learning to code my first, simple response based bot in Discord. I am writing the code in Python, and hosting the code through Replit (as it has a way to keep your bot 'online' 24/7).

I have figured out how to respond to key/trigger words from users, but I am having trouble coding the following:

When the user types one of the 'trigger' words like the word 'death', I want the bot to look in the dictionary (called 'quotes') I created for the 'trigger' words, find the key for 'death', which has a list attached as its value pair, and then return one of the values on the list, randomly.

This is how the lists look like within the dictionary (not in full, to save space)

```
quotes = {
  'death': [
    'Even death is not to be feared by one who has lived wisely.', 
    'Ardently do today what must be done. Who knows? Tomorrow, death comes.',
    'To be idle is a short road to death and to be diligent is a way of life; foolish people are idle, wise people are diligent.'
  ],
  'wisdom':['empty'],
  'hello':['Hello!']
}
```

The code I tried to use (this is what interacts with the Discord API, and it seems to be working)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    msg = message.content

    for trigger_word in quotes:
      if trigger_word in msg.lower():
        await message.channel.send(random_quotes(quotes))
```

And the extra Python code I tried to write:

```
def random_quotes(trigger_word):
  for trigger_word in quotes:
    return (random.choice(trigger_word))
```

This returns (when using in discord, with the bot online) a random letter from the first key:value pair I have (in this case, a random letter from the word 'death').

Am I missing something on the Python side of coding, or on the side of interacting with the Discord API?
I chose this list within dictionary setup to make it easier to add lots of different 'trigger' words, all with multiple possible responses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use `dict.items()` to iterate over pairs of keywords and lists of quotes, then `random.choice()` from that keyword's list:

```
import random

quotes = {
    "death": [
        "Even death is not to be feared by one who has lived wisely.",
        "Ardently do today what must be done. Who knows? Tomorrow, death comes.",
        "To be idle is a short road to death and to be diligent is a way of life; foolish people are idle, wise people are diligent.",
    ],
    "wisdom": ["empty"],
    "hello": ["Hello!"],
}


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    msg = message.content

    for trigger_word, quote_texts in quotes.items():
        if trigger_word in msg.lower():
            quote = random.choice(quote_texts)
            await message.channel.send(quote)
            break  # only trigger on one word per message
```

## EDIT

To support multiple keywords, you can just gather up all of the possible quotes, then choose among them. (This pooling gives a more even distribution of quotes in case one keyword has more quotes than another.)

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    msg = message.content

    possible_quotes = []
    for trigger_word, quote_texts in quotes.items():
        if trigger_word in msg.lower():
            possible_quotes.extend(quote_texts)
    if possible_quotes:
        quote = random.choice(possible_quotes)
        await message.channel.send(quote)
```

Comment: This worked 99%! I tested it out and it returns a random option from the list, depending on the trigger word used (so it picks randomly from the list I have for the word 'death' for example). I also tested it out to see if it triggers multiples times for the same, or different words, but the 'break' solved that issue as well.

What I am thinking about now is if there is a way to fix the following: If I have death and hello in my message (order doesn't matter), the bot will always return a quote from death, instead one from hello some of the times (probably due to the order in the dictionary)

Comment: Of course there is. Should it return a quote from both, or choose randomly between the keywords to use? Or should it pool together all phrases from the matching keywords and choose randomly within that pool?

Comment: I was hoping for the last option - from all the trigger words that were used in the message, it picks one randomly (both a random key, and then a random value attached to that key).

Comment: I added the code you suggested, but ran into the following issue: the bot now responds by printing everything attached to the key:value pair. So in the case of 'death', it sends all three quotes. If I add another trigger word, it just adds all of the quotes attached to that trigger word as well to the end of the message of the bot. 

It is as if it simply displays everything stored in the lists for the key invoked by the trigger word.

EDIT: I really appreciate all your help so far! It has been illuminating and very helpful!

Comment: @ToldiReloaded Oops, fixed my typo in the last line :-)

Comment: Ah, that resolved the issue! Thanks once again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you mean but try to do this, replace:

```
await message.channel.send(random_quotes(quotes))
```

with:

```
await message.channel.send(random_quotes(trigger_word))
```

and:

```
for trigger_word in quotes:
   return (random.choice(trigger_word))
```

with:

```
return random.choice(quotes[trigger_word])
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked for getting me past receiving a single letter as a reply from the bot. But now it only gives the first value of the list for each key (even though the random.choice was added). I guess I have to test it a bit more. Thanks though!

Comment: Seriously? In my case every thing worked... maybe you were unlucky and got the same "random" thing couple of times

Comment: Yeah, tested it about 10 times, always got the same one back. :/ Started/restarted bot, didn't fix the issue. But it looks like the other advice resolved this issue. Thanks for your input though :)